# Backbone Marionette: Don't render composite view if collection is empty

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I have a CompositeView where I fetch its collection on initialize.

```
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = this.model.things;
    this.collection.fetch();
  },
```

How do I *not* render this composite view if its collection is empty?

I'm aware of the `EmptyView`, but that still renders the composite view's template. I want to not render anything if the collection is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer ended up being to render the composite view after the `fetch`'s deferred objected returned.

```
initialize: function() {
  var self = this;
  this.collection = this.model.localFoods;
  this.collection.fetch().then(function() {
    self.render();
  });
}
```

Current score

async:23, me:0

Async wins!

Comment: I have the same problem. Instead of fetching I check for the size of the collection and only render if it's > 1. But it is getting rendered regardless of whether I call render() or not. And also it is complaining that object has no method render when I use self. (I've been using this). Any help there?

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> When the collection's "reset" event is fired, it will only re-render
>   the collection within the composite, and not the wrapper template

So pass `{reset: true}` to the `fetch()`, so the collection will automatically be re-rendered:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection = this.model.things;
    this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
}
```